# Edited Featured module in opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using opencart 2.0.1.1. I have removed wishlist and compare button from featured module. Now I am facing a problem that the cart button is at left position but I want it to place it center..

Please tell me how can I place it in center?

Comment: are you remove wishlist & compare button from only featured module? have you remove it button in other module & also category page?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your site source > catalog > view > theme > default > stylesheet > stylesheet.css > & then find below css & then Replace to `width: 100%;` instead of `width: 60%;` in below css.

```
.product-thumb .button-group button {
    width: 60%;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #888;
    line-height: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... i figured out... Thanks for sparing your precious time for me. thanks again.